# Show that the map $T_U:W\to U^{*}$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$T_U$ is defined by $(T_U\textbf w)(\textbf u)=\tau(\textbf w, \textbf u)$ for $\textbf w \in W$, $\textbf u \in U$.

I know from a previous part to the question that $U^{\perp}=\{\textbf w \in W : \tau (\textbf w, \textbf u) = \textbf 0$ for all $\textbf u \in U \}$ so does this mean that the function, $\tau$, is the dot product of $\textbf w$ and $\textbf u$? And therefore does this mean that the question is asking me to show that the dot product is linear?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to say $\tau:W \times V \to \mathbb K$ is a bilinear map where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $\mathbb K$.

Comment: It's missing some context.. There must be somewhere in your question where you define $\tau$

Comment: I've defined $\tau$ now, sorry I forgot about it before.

Comment: $\tau$ isn't the dot product - its arguments even come from two different spaces! It is just some bilinear map $W\times V\to\mathbb{K}$. It's not unusual to use the $U^\perp$ notation for orthogonality with respect to other bilinear forms than the dot product. Since you are given that $\tau$ is bilinear, the question is merely asking you to see that this implies the linearity of $T_U$ - this seems to me to be mainly an exercise in distinguishing linearity of $(T_U\mathbf{w})(\mathbf{u})$ in $\mathbf{w}$ from linearity in $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: So would Exodd's answer be correct or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's linear since
$$
T_U(aw)(u)=\tau(aw,v)=a\tau(w,v)=aT_U(w)(u)
$$
Sorry for the lack of explanation, but I'm writing from a cellphone